# identifier FilterConnect CommuniatPort is undefined

Tags: c++, kernel

I have a minifilter driver that use communication ports to connect to user mode. The minifilter kernel driver is fine. The user mode code unfortunately have some issues.

User-mode code:

```
#include <fltUser.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "fltlib.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "fltmgr.lib")

HANDLE port = NULL;
int main() {
    printf("Hello there\n");
    if (port == NULL) {
        if (FilterConnectCommunicationPort(L"\\nmf", 0, NULL, 0, NULL, &port)) {
            printf("Connected to Kernel\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

List of errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0059   function call is not allowed in a constant expression   kernelConnect   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\fltUser.h    94  
Error (active)  E0059   function call is not allowed in a constant expression   kernelConnect   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\fltUserStructures.h  27  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "HANDLE" is undefined    kernelConnect   C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\kernelConnect\Source.cpp    9   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "FilterConnectCommunicationPort" is undefined    kernelConnect   C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\kernelConnect\Source.cpp    13  
Error   C1012   unmatched parenthesis: missing ')'  kernelConnect   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\fltUserStructures.h  27
```

As you can see, there are two errors, that I don't understand:

1. identifier "HANDLE" is undefined kernelConnect
2. identifier "FilterConnectCommunicationPort" is undefined

I confirmed that FilterConnectCommunicationPort is indeed in the fltuser header. but in the source code, visual studio could find a definition to the function but not a declaration.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Try including `windows.h` before `fltUser.h`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik now i am getting: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK1104 cannot open file 'fltmgr.lib' kernelConnect C:\Users\Abdul\source\repos\kernelConnect\LINK 1

Comment: [The documentation for `FilterConnectCommunicationPort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fltuser/nf-fltuser-filterconnectcommunicationport) states that one should link with `FltLib.lib`, not with `fltmgr.lib`